# Browserify arbitrary project file as entry point with module.exports as global

Tags: javascript, browserify

I have a browserify project that is part of a family of communcating libraries that do not use browserify. The established way to make javascript APIs available is with `<script>` tags. The way I use browserify is: say I have a module `m` exposing functions `f` and `g`. I make a file

```
global.f = require('m').f;
global.g = require('m').g;
```

run browserify with that file as an entry point.

However the potential entry points have become too many. It would help very much if it were possible for browserify to automatically throw all the `module.exports` of a particular file into `global`. Is there an equivalent to this available?

Answer (score 0):

I think this project is what you're looking for:

https://github.com/DeepElement/browserify-bridge